# My form is not being submitted to firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I intend on using firebase firestore as a backend service to store data, authenticate users and hide content from users that aren't signed in.
From tutorials I was watching and using, I was able to connect my site to firebase, and after the codes I had written, the form on the page supposed to submit to firestore but then I get no response and no error message also, I don't know what to do.
I've checked for solutions to my particular issue but I haven't seen any so far.
This is the form

```
  <form id="signup-form" class="form form-horizontal">

                                <!-- Investment Plan Info Modal -->
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="planInfoModal_starter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="planInfoModal_starterLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <!-- modal header -->
                                                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times; </button>
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="planInfoModal_starterLabel">
                                            <font color=""> STARTER ACCOUNT </font> 
                                                    </h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- modal body -->
                                                <div class="modal-body" style="font-size:15px; line-height:20px;">

                                                    <div class="" style="margin-bottom:;">
                                                        <div class=" ">
                                                            <div class=" ">
                                                                <div style="min-height:;" class="">
                                                                                                            <div class="plan_item">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                                                            Minimum Investment:     $500                                        </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="plan_item">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                                                            Maximum Investment:     $9999                                        </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="plan_item">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                                                            On Weekly ROI Model:     200% weekly                                        </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="plan_item">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                                                            On Compounding ROI Model:     400% weekly                                        </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="plan_item">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                                                            Referral Commission:     5% on referred users' first deposits and 1.5% on subsequents.                                        </div>

                                                                </div>
                                                                <br>
                                                            </div> 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <!-- modal footer -->
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                                        </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /. this modal ends-->

                                    <div class="modal fade" id="planInfoModal_basic" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="planInfoModal_basicLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <!-- modal header -->
                                                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times; </button>
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="planInfoModal_basicLabel">
                                                        <font color=""> BASIC ACCOUNT </font> 
                                                    </h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- modal body -->
                                                <div class="modal-body" style="font-size:15px; line-height:20px;">

                                                    <div class="" style="margin-bottom:;">
                                                        <div class=" ">
                                                            <div class=" ">
                                                                <div style="min-height:;" class="">
                                                                                                            <div class="plan_item">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                                                            Minimum Investment:     $10,000                                        </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="plan_item">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                                                            Maximum Investment:     $99,999                                        </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="plan_item">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                                                            On Weekly ROI Model:     300% weekly                                        </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="plan_item">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                                                            On Compounding ROI Model:     500% weekly                                        </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="plan_item">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                                                            Referral Commission:5% on referred users' first deposits and 1.5% on subsequents</div>

                                                                </div>
                                                                <br>
                                                            </div> 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <!-- modal footer -->
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                                        </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /. this modal ends-->


                                <input type="hidden" name="investment_plan" value="basic">
                                <input type="hidden" name="investment_planID" value="2">
                                <input type="hidden" name="min_capital" value="10000">
                                <input type="hidden" name="max_capital" value="72000">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                                        <h4>
                                            Chosen Investment Plan: 
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-warning" style="text-align: center; background:; color: #fff; padding: 10px; font-size:120%; margin-bottom:20px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#planInfoModal_basic"> 
                                                BASIC ACCOUNT 
                                            </a>
                                            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                                            <a href="..\..\signup.html">Change Plan?</a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>

                                <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <!-- <div class="col-sm-2"></div> -->
                            <div class="col-sm-12"> 
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                                                        <input type="tel" class="form-control my_input" name="investment_capital" id="invest-capital" value="" placeholder="Investment Capital (min: $10,000 - max: $72,000.00)" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- <div class="col-sm-2"></div> -->
                                <div class="col-sm-12"> 
                                    <h4>Choose ROI Model</h4>
                                    <select id="ROI-modl" name="Choose_ROI_Model">
                                        <option value="">-ROI Model-</option>

                                        <option value="1">
                                            Weekly Interest
                                        </option>

                                        <option value="2">
                                            Compounding (Monthly) Interest
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="alert-danger"></div>  
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <!-- <div class="col-sm-2"></div> -->
                            <div class="col-sm-12"> 

                                    <select id="depost-id" name="deposit_typeID" class="form-control my_input">
                                        <option value="">-Investment Funding Medium- </option>

                                    <option value="1"> 
                                        BITCOIN (BTC)  
                                    </option> 

                                    <option value="2"> 
                                        ETHERIUM (ETH)  
                                    </option> 
                                    </select>
                                                <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
                            <div class="text-center"><b>Current Rates</b></div>


                            <!--Currency Converter widget by FreeCurrencyRates.com -->
                                    <div id='gcw_mainFjLs3vMJc' class='gcw_mainFjLs3vMJc'></div>
                                    <a id='gcw_siteFjLs3vMJc' href='https://freecurrencyrates.com/en/'><!-- FreeCurrencyRates.com --></a>
                                    <script>function reloadFjLs3vMJc(){ var sc = document.getElementById('scFjLs3vMJc');if (sc) sc.parentNode.removeChild(sc);sc = document.createElement('script');sc.type = 'text/javascript';sc.charset = 'UTF-8';sc.async = true;sc.id='scFjLs3vMJc';sc.src = 'https://freecurrencyrates.com/en/widget-vertical-editable?iso=USDBTCETHLTCXRP&df=1&p=FjLs3vMJc&v=fits&source=fcr&width=270&width_title=0&firstrowvalue=1&thm=A6C9E2,FCFDFD,4297D7,5C9CCC,FFFFFF,C5DBEC,FCFDFD,2E6E9E,000000&title=Currency%20Converter&tzo=-60';var div = document.getElementById('gcw_mainFjLs3vMJc');div.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, div);} reloadFjLs3vMJc(); </script>
                                    <!-- put custom styles here: .gcw_mainFjLs3vMJc{}, .gcw_headerFjLs3vMJc{}, .gcw_ratesFjLs3vMJc{}, .gcw_sourceFjLs3vMJc{} -->
                                    <!--End of Currency Converter widget by FreeCurrencyRates.com --></div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control my_input" id="first-name" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name">
                                    <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control my_input" id="other-names" name="othernames" value="" placeholder="Other Names">
                                    <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                                    <select name="country" class='form-control my_input populate' id='country' style='min-height:35px; color:#000;' >
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
                                        <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                                        <option value="AL">Albania</option>
                                        <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
                                        <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
                                        <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
                                        <option value="AO">Angola</option>
                                        <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
                                        <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
                                        <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                                        <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
                                        <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
                                        <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
                                        <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                                        <option value="AT">Austria</option>
                                        <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
                                        <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
                                        <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
                                        <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
                                        <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
                                        <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
                                        <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
                                        <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
                                        <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
                                        <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
                                        <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
                                        <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
                                        <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                                        <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
                                        <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
                                        <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
                                        <option value="BQ">British Antarctic Territory</option>
                                        <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                                        <option value="VG">British Virgin Islands</option>
                                        <option value="BN">Brunei</option>
                                        <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
                                        <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
                                        <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
                                        <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
                                        <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
                                        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                                        <option value="CT">Canton and Enderbury Islands</option>
                                        <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
                                        <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
                                        <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
                                        <option value="TD">Chad</option>
                                        <option value="CL">Chile</option>
                                        <option value="CN">China</option>
                                        <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
                                        <option value="CC">Cocos [Keeling] Islands</option>
                                        <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
                                        <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
                                        <option value="CG">Congo - Brazzaville</option>
                                        <option value="CD">Congo - Kinshasa</option>
                                        <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
                                        <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
                                        <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
                                        <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
                                        <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
                                        <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
                                        <option value="CI">Côte d’Ivoire</option>
                                        <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
                                        <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
                                        <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
                                        <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
                                        <option value="NQ">Dronning Maud Land</option>
                                        <option value="DD">East Germany</option>
                                        <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
                                        <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
                                        <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
                                        <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                                        <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
                                        <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
                                        <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
                                        <option value="FK">Falkland Islands</option>
                                        <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
                                        <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
                                        <option value="FI">Finland</option>
                                        <option value="FR">France</option>
                                        <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
                                        <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
                                        <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
                                        <option value="FQ">French Southern and Antarctic Territories</option>
                                        <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
                                        <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
                                        <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
                                        <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                                        <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
                                        <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
                                        <option value="GR">Greece</option>
                                        <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
                                        <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
                                        <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
                                        <option value="GU">Guam</option>
                                        <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
                                        <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
                                        <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
                                        <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                                        <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
                                        <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
                                        <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
                                        <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
                                        <option value="HK">Hong Kong SAR China</option>
                                        <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
                                        <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
                                        <option value="IN">India</option>
                                        <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
                                        <option value="IR">Iran</option>
                                        <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
                                        <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
                                        <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
                                        <option value="IL">Israel</option>
                                        <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                                        <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
                                        <option value="JP">Japan</option>
                                        <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
                                        <option value="JT">Johnston Island</option>
                                        <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
                                        <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
                                        <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
                                        <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
                                        <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
                                        <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                                        <option value="LA">Laos</option>
                                        <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
                                        <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
                                        <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
                                        <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
                                        <option value="LY">Libya</option>
                                        <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
                                        <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
                                        <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
                                        <option value="MO">Macau SAR China</option>
                                        <option value="MK">Macedonia</option>
                                        <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
                                        <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
                                        <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
                                        <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
                                        <option value="ML">Mali</option>
                                        <option value="MT">Malta</option>
                                        <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
                                        <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
                                        <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
                                        <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
                                        <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
                                        <option value="FX">Metropolitan France</option>
                                        <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
                                        <option value="FM">Micronesia</option>
                                        <option value="MI">Midway Islands</option>
                                        <option value="MD">Moldova</option>
                                        <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
                                        <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
                                        <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
                                        <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
                                        <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
                                        <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
                                        <option value="MM">Myanmar [Burma]</option>
                                        <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
                                        <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
                                        <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
                                        <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
                                        <option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                                        <option value="NT">Neutral Zone</option>
                                        <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
                                        <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
                                        <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
                                        <option value="NE">Niger</option>
                                        <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
                                        <option value="NU">Niue</option>
                                        <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
                                        <option value="KP">North Korea</option>
                                        <option value="VD">North Vietnam</option>
                                        <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                                        <option value="NO">Norway</option>
                                        <option value="OM">Oman</option>
                                        <option value="PC">Pacific Islands Trust Territory</option>
                                        <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
                                        <option value="PW">Palau</option>
                                        <option value="PS">Palestinian Territories</option>
                                        <option value="PA">Panama</option>
                                        <option value="PZ">Panama Canal Zone</option>
                                        <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
                                        <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
                                        <option value="YD">People's Democratic Republic of Yemen</option>
                                        <option value="PE">Peru</option>
                                        <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
                                        <option value="PN">Pitcairn Islands</option>
                                        <option value="PL">Poland</option>
                                        <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
                                        <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                                        <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
                                        <option value="RO">Romania</option>
                                        <option value="RU">Russia</option>
                                        <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
                                        <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
                                        <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
                                        <option value="SH">Saint Helena</option>
                                        <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                                        <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
                                        <option value="MF">Saint Martin</option>
                                        <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                                        <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
                                        <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
                                        <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
                                        <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
                                        <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
                                        <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
                                        <option value="CS">Serbia and Montenegro</option>
                                        <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
                                        <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
                                        <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
                                        <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
                                        <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
                                        <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
                                        <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
                                        <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
                                        <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
                                        <option value="KR">South Korea</option>
                                        <option value="ES">Spain</option>
                                        <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
                                        <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
                                        <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
                                        <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
                                        <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
                                        <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
                                        <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
                                        <option value="SY">Syria</option>
                                        <option value="ST">São Tomé and Príncipe</option>
                                        <option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
                                        <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
                                        <option value="TZ">Tanzania</option>
                                        <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
                                        <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
                                        <option value="TG">Togo</option>
                                        <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
                                        <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
                                        <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                                        <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
                                        <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
                                        <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
                                        <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                                        <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
                                        <option value="UM">U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                                        <option value="PU">U.S. Miscellaneous Pacific Islands</option>
                                        <option value="VI">U.S. Virgin Islands</option>
                                        <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
                                        <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
                                        <option value="SU">Union of Soviet Socialist Republics</option>
                                        <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
                                        <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                                        <option value="US">United States</option>
                                        <option value="ZZ">Unknown or Invalid Region</option>
                                        <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
                                        <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
                                        <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
                                        <option value="VA">Vatican City</option>
                                        <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
                                        <option value="VN">Vietnam</option>
                                        <option value="WK">Wake Island</option>
                                        <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
                                        <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
                                        <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
                                        <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
                                        <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
                                        </select>
                                    <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control my_input" id="city" name="city" value="" placeholder="City">
                                    <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control my_input" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
                                    <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                                    <input type="tel" maxlength="" class="form-control my_input" id="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone">
                                    <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control my_input" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="New Password">
                                    <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control my_input" id="retypepassword" name="retype_password" value="" placeholder="Repeat Password">
                                    <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control my_input" id="referreremail" name="referrer_email" value="" placeholder="Ref. (optional)">
                                    <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                                    <input type='checkbox' name='terms' id="terms" value='accept'> 
                                    <label for="terms" style="font-weight:normal;">I agree with the </label> <a href="terms">Terms of Service</a>.
                                    <div class="alert-danger"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                    <button type="submit" name="regbtn" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg pull-right">proceed</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

I then connected firebase to my web app using the firebase SDK and stored some consts also.
This is the Javascript part.

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API_KEY",
  authDomain: "the-joint-ffb4a.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://the-joint-ffb4a.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "the-joint-ffb4a",
  storageBucket: "the-joint-ffb4a.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "360288748444",
  appId: "APP_ID",
  measurementId: "G-W8P4JVFG7X"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//make auth and firestore references
const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();

//Signup
const signupForm = document.querySelector("#signup-form");
signupForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

//Get Values
const investment_capital = signupForm["invest-capital"].value;
const ROI_Model = signupForm["ROI-modl"].value;
const Investment_Funding_Medium = signupForm["depost-id"].value;
const firstname = signupForm["first-name"].value;
const othernames = signupForm["other-names"].value;
const country = signupForm["country"].value;
const city = signupForm["city"].value;
const email = signupForm["email"].value;
const phone = signupForm["phone"].value;
const password = signupForm["password"].value;
const retypepassword = signupForm["retypepassword"].value;
const referreremail = signupForm["referreremail"].value;

console.log(
  investment_capital,
  ROI_Model,
  Investment_Funding_Medium,
  firstname,
  othernames,
  country,
  city,
  email,
  phone,
  password,
  retypepassword,
  referreremail
);
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: if I were you I would probably reformat your example code a bit nicer

Comment: Your submit event handler cancels the submission (`e.preventDefault();`) which is fine, but then *does nothing else*. If you want to post to firebase, you have to actually tell your code to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path, you just need to call firestore's `.add()` method and pass an object representing your form data as a parameter

Update your event listener with the following:

```
//Signup
const signupForm = document.querySelector("#signup-form");
signupForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // feel free to change the object keys to match your data model 

  db.add({
   investment_capital: signupForm["invest-capital"].value,
   roi_model: signupForm["ROI-modl"].value,
   investment_funding_medium: signupForm["depost-id"].value,
   firstname: signupForm["first-name"].value,
   othernames: signupForm["other-names"].value,
   country: signupForm["country"].value,
   city: signupForm["city"].value,
   email: signupForm["email"].value,
   phone: signupForm["phone"].value,
   password: signupForm["password"].value,
   retypepassword: signupForm["retypepassword"].value,
   referreremail: signupForm["referreremail"].value
  })
  .then(function(docRef) {
    // data was added successfully
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // an error occurred when adding the data
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
  });
});
```

See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) for additional detail